# Insurance law, DIY improvements gone awry

Tags: liability, insurance

I have watched a few videos online where DIY projects went awry. For instance, tree removal with tree winding up on a homeowner's roof and auto.

What are the general insurance rules regarding such projects that result in loss?
When would such losses be covered, and under what circumstances would these losses not be covered?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find "general" rules here.  What governs is the actual policy.  If in doubt, read the policy.  It will give specific details about what is covered and what is excluded.

Comment: in general, an "Accident" will be covered.  Something considered negligent may not be; this will be governed state-to-state in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Read your policy

Insurance contracts spell out in excruciating detail in which circumstances they are on risk and which they aren’t. For [example](https://secure.budgetdirect.com.au/branding/resources/BUDD/legal/home/HPDSBUDD.pdf).

In that policy, page 39 excludes "Loss or damage caused by lopping or felling of trees when this is performed or authorised by you, your family, or a household member".

So DIY tree felling is at your risk. So is authorising a contractor to fell a tree (although you would presumably look to the contractor's insurer for restitution)

You would be covered if a neighbour (or their contractor) dropped a tree onto your house or if a utility company did so. They didn't need or get your authorisation so the exclusion does not apply.